# When, Why, and Where using Lock tables in Web Applications

Tags: php, mysql, web, concurrency, transactions

i have to write a very complex application for works.
All my previous software were software used in a local area and not application on cloud.

I notice that all the query that modify the database are subjected to concurrency problem.
I've just solved the problem using write lock and transaction in serializable isolation level.
But in only reading query i have to make a read lock? what happen if i read some records from a table while another query deleting some of these records? i have a dirty read.

So can you explain how do you usually resolve the query concurrency problem?. I use php.
Do you usually use write lock? as far as now i've never notice that problem. i work as Web developer in a small company and i don't now why i never occurred in this solution.

thank you, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Normally there is no need to use locks in an application and they are best avoided whenever possible as they do cause issues with scalability. You can normally engineer out the need for locksby looking at different ways of implementing a solution to the specific problem you are facing

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your writes in a transaction, don't use locks.

In PHP it's far too easy for your application to crash out and leave a lock in place, rendering your entire database unusable until that's reset. Transactions will automatically release when committed, rolled back, or the connection is dropped.

I think most of what you're talking about is misplaced paranoia. If you're using a proper database engine like InnoDB you won't have problems.

Comment: I don't think that using innodb is sufficient. If a writing query depends on a previous select query, i must know that the previous select query data is not changed when i perform the update query. Starting a transaction don't make select query waiting for an already started transaction. What if the reading data is the amount of a banking account. More than one query can read the amount, allowing a payment. But when the first payment is made the amount is different, and can not be enough for the second payment. But the second payment is already allowed

Comment: This is why you never, **ever** trust your reads if you're doing math like that. Instead you do *differential updates* like `UPDATE bank_balances SET balance=balance-? WHERE id=?` instead of assignment like `UPDATE bank_balances SET balance=?`. If you're really concerned about consistency, then you need to employ a subselect so the whole thing runs atomically. If your differential update forces the value negative, roll it back and produce an error.